# Preventing XSS in user URL input

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-core, xss

I have an application with an input field, that allows the user to submit a URL, which will be displayed as a link on the page (in a SPA written in React).

I would like the user to be able to submit relative urls as well as absolute ones. For example (all of the below should be a fine input):

```
https://stackoverflow.com
stackoverflow.com
http://example.com
localhost:1234
localhost
...
```

I'm trying to prevent XSS attacks. So that when the user submits `javascript:alert('hacked')` in the URL input, it shouldn't work.

The way I was thinking of doing it is to simply prefix the input with `http://` (if it's not in the input) already. So that the final result would be `http://javascript:alert('hacked')`

On the server side I'm using ASP.NET Core and I have a model that looks something like:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyApp.Models {
    public class LinkModel {
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Url]
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Notice the `Url` attribute, when I test - `http://javascript:alert('hacked')` it is "valid". Which leads me to believe it's ok and it's not a XSS attack vector. I also tested it in Chrome and Firefox and it seems to be "safe".

Is that the case? Am I missing something? Is adding `http://` to an input before passing it to the server enough to prevent XSS attacks. Please let me know if I can clarify.

Comment: have you read [this section for recommendations?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting?view=aspnetcore-3.1#protecting-your-application-against-xss), you can also sanitize the text/url before putting it in the href e.g.: using [HtmlSanitizer](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer).

Comment: I'm actually passing the data from an ASP.NET controller in JSON to a react front-end. So my question was more in general, I suppose. (I've updated my question if it would clarify things a bit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are accepting a URL from a user, there are a few things you need to be aware of. You mentioned the `javascript:` vector. There are also `data:` urls (for example, `data:text/html;base64,PHNjcmlwdD5hbGVydCgiSGVsbG8iKTs8L3NjcmlwdD4=`which will pop up an alert that says "hello".) In my opinion, you need to parse the url, and ensure the scheme/protocol is in a white list (for example, `https` and `http`). This whitelist will depend on your needs. Maybe you want people to be able to use `mailto:` or `slack:` links, but you need to be aware of the kinds of attacks or abuses each protocol may have. Just appending http is kinda weird, and may end up having a hole. For example `http://test@http://example.com` could pass the username `http` and password `//test` to the host `example.com` using [basic HTTP authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). I doubt this will work in modern browsers, but it's possible.

For what it's worth, `http://javascript:alert(1)` should never be interpreted as javascript. I would guess that the browser interprets `javascript` as the host (like stackoverflow.com is the host). But if a host has a computer named `javascript` on their network, it would resolve to an error page. If you implement the whitelist correctly, you don't need to worry about stuff like this.

Next, you need to assure that you are escaping/encoding the URL properly when displaying it. Something like this: `<a href="escape(url)">name</a>` you need to make sure a user can't put `"` in the url and break out of the html attribute. Consider something like [system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder.urlencode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder.urlencode?view=netframework-4.8).

You also need to be aware that a user could still link a valid https site that is malicious. An example would be a phishing site that looks like yours, or maybe just some site with malware downloads. Many sites will create a warning popup that tells the user that they are leaving the site. That may be something you want to do, but it really depends. I am not sure how helpful those are, but if you are worried about users getting tricked into leaving, it's something to think about.

Finally, a user could link to an existing page on your site and STILL be malicious - for example, [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). You need to be careful about preventing these kinds of pages from existing at all. Imagine someone linking to `https://example.com/account/delete` and then an unsuspecting user deletes their own account.

edit: I personally would not bother letting users put in URLs without the scheme, as it means you'll have to assume `http`. I would validate on the client side that it's a URL (including protocol), and then check if it's in a whitelist.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, much appreciated. In your first example `data:` being an attack vector. Wouldn't an `http://` prefix render it invalid just like the `javascript:` one? The problem with your last suggestion is that I would like to make it a bit easier for the user if they're to type the url (instead of copy-paste), most would just go `google.com`.

Comment: Say that I go for your suggestion and have the user input the protocol. What would be a good way to validate the url. I've seen some crazy RegExs trying to do it. Any suggestions? Links? Reading material?

Comment: yes. `http://data` would be like linking to a computer named data on the user's network. It's a bit odd to do, IMO. I know what you mean about how it's easier for users to type `google.com` rather than `https://google.com` but presuming `http` could cause errors as well. If the site is not listening on port 80, then it would just time out. Most sites will have an http->https redirect, but you mentioned some localhost sites as well.

Comment: For validating the URL client side, you don't need anything fancy (and I would discourage it). `<input type="url" pattern="https?://.+" required />`  This would just assure http or https. It is still absolutely critical that this is validated server-side, because an attacker can bypass any client-side validation. On the server side, you want to rely on built in URL parsers, not a regex.

Comment: Yep, absolutely, I'll do the server side validation as well (already done by asp.net and their `Url` validation attribute). Thanks again for the answer.